# Textarea's Parent Resizing Stops Working After Setting Height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a parent div with a textarea inside. When you dynamically grab the corner of the textarea to resize it, the parent div resizes as well. Great!

However, when I set the height of the div using javascript, then the textarea will no longer adjust the parent div.

How can I set the height of the parent div using Javascript, and still have the height adjust from the browser as well?

This is just an example. I have other things inside the div I want to resize, so I can't just resize the textarea and keep the div height as auto.

```
<style>
.parent{
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
 resize: vertical;
}
</style>

<div class="parent" id="container">
<textarea class="child" id="content">
  Hello World!
</textarea>
</div>
<button id="btn">
  Set Height
</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = "90px";
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried using min-height instead of a fixed height?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is set the height of the parent div back to `auto` after you adjust its height. Make sure you adjust the height of the children as well or else it will jump right back to the size of the textarea.

`document.getElementById("container").style.height = "auto";`

Here is the completed code:

```
<style>
.parent{
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
 resize: vertical;
}
</style>

<div class="parent" id="container">
<textarea class="child" id="content">
  Hello World!
</textarea>
</div>
<button id="btn">
  Set Height
</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = "100px";
    document.getElementById("content").style.height = "90px";
    document.getElementById("container").style.height = "auto";
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want the textarea adjust on the size of the parent on button click. And have the parent's height adjust on textarea on resize.

If so, set the `.parent` to have `height: auto;`, and then on button click - instead of setting its height, set the height of its `.child` element.

```js
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function() {
  document.querySelector(".child").style.height = "100px";
});
```

```css
.parent {
  background-color: blue;
  height: auto;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent" id="container">
  <textarea class="child">
      Hello World!
  </textarea>
</div>
<button id="btn">Set Height</button>
```

Comment: Although this accomplishes what I want to see, it won't work for my use case. I need an answer that can set the height of the parent div, as there are other things going on inside it.

Comment: Okay, so it must be the parent div to change height. Wait.

Comment: I figured it out actually. After you set the height of the parent element, you reset it to auto again with `document.getElementById("container").style.height = "auto";`

Comment: Oh. That's awesome! I was about to update my answer to use `MutationObserver` but it seems you're fine on your own now. 

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you want to be able to resize the textarea within the parent div after the parent div has been given a fixed height.

This would mean that the textarea should not overflow the parent div. To implement this, you simply have to set the overflow property of the parent div to **hidden**.

See this [result on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/szuan5yx/3/)

```
.parent {
  overflow: hidden;  
}
```

Also have a look at [documentation for the CSS overflow property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: Sorry if I didn't make things clear...I'll try to give a more detailed explanation. What I need is to set the height of the parent div but NOT have it "fixed". I want to give it a specific height based on user events, but still have it scalable by the browser.

Comment: Do you mean you want the parent div to be responsive?. So it should auto size relative to the browser window size ?